# Multiple issues with flexbox and min-height 100vh

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog, flexbox

My page looks exactly like this

```
<article>
    <header>header</header>

    <section>section</section>

    <footer>footer</footer>
</article>
```

Although this might look too easy, I need it to do 3 things:

1) If the `section` is smaller than the available height, the footer should be at the bottom (and if the section gets bigger, the footer will simply be at the end (scrolling) of the page): [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/1rma8167/1/)

2) It should work in IE10 (check the demo in IE10 and you'll see that flexbox doesn't work very well: [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/1rma8167/6/)

3) Finally, if a huge modal dialog is shown (very tall) the footer should be at the bottom of the page: [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/1rma8167/4/)

Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you've accomplished **Item #1** already. `flex-grow` is the right way to go, in my view.

For **Item #2**, try adding [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix) to your CSS, which are necessary for flexbox to work in IE10 (and Safari 8). See browser support info here: http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

For a quick way to add all the prefixes you need, post your CSS in the left panel here: [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/).

Also note that IE10 does not support the [current flexbox specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox/).

It only supports the [old "tweener" syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-css3-flexbox-20111129/), which almost no other browser uses.

> Bottom line regarding IE10:
>
> *The March 2012 [tweener] draft does not have an equivalent for
>   `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink`, or `flex-basis` -- these properties can
>   only be set via the `flex` shorthand property.*
>
> <sup>Source: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/flexbox/info</sup>

For **Item #3**, I'll need to work on that when I have more time. Maybe somebody can't help you in another answer. Just keep in mind the modal in your code is absolutely positioned, which means it has been removed from the document flow, and the footer doesn't even know it exists.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping. I've updated the demo for item2 and I still have the layout issue (You're right about item 1 :)

Comment: Instead of `flex-grow`, try using the `flex` shorthand. See my revised answer.

Comment: Not exactly sure what the shorthand notation of `flex-grow: 1` is. But according to the documentation I get the impression it should be: `flex: 1` ? [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1rma8167/8/) But this even looks worse in IE :(

Comment: I'll look a bit more later, but it appears that ie10 and flexbox don't play well together: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18711282/3597276

Comment: and note this detailed article from Microsoft, as well.. https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh673531(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Item #2 is easily fixed without flexbox, but simply use `min-height`: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1rma8167/12/). So, item #3 is still open, but maybe the best thing we can do is set the dialog to a max-height of 100% and make it scrollable ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1rma8167/13/)) Let me know if you have a better solution!!

Comment: In researching for an item3 solution, I found this article. Hopefully it helps: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/11/07/css-overlay-techniques/